# Canvas that created from video raising "Tainted canvases may not be exported." error when saving

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, html5-video

I'm creating snapshot from HTML5 video, using [this example](http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/video-canvas-screenshot.html). Video is hosted on 3rd party servers, that I can't control.

So I wanted to save image, but `toDataURL` failing because of security reason.

Here is error: `Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

I guess there is a solution for image. `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"` something like that. [Here](http://squired.co.uk/todataurl-fails-on-html5-canvas-with-embedded-image/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).

I tried `videoDomElm.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"`, but no luck.

Is there any solution for video?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crossOrigin='anonymous'` is only half the solution to passing cross-domain security requirements. It causes the browser to read the response headers and not taint the canvas if the headers allow for cross-origin access of the content.

The other half of the solution is for the server to be configured to send the proper cross-origin permissions in its response headers. Without the server being configured to allow cross-origin access, the canvas will still be tainted.

The only ways to satisfy cross-origin security are:

1. Have the video originate on the same domain as your web pages.
2. Have the video server configured to send the appropriate cross-origin access in its headers.

There are no workarounds -- you must satisfy the security restrictions.